# Is there any way I can compile .PAS files into .COM files?

Tags: pascal

I am making a retro text adventure game in Turbo Pascal that will be played in MS-DOS, and I want it to be in the COM file format. I've looked it up and have found nothing on this subject. If you can help me that would be greatly appreciated.
Something other than that, whenever I try to run my program (compiled into EXE) from DosBox it can't run due to "This program cannot be run in DOS mode". Is this because I'm using Turbo Pascal 7 and need to downgrade? Thanks a lot of you can figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your TP7 to target dos, not windows. Note that you might have an Windows only TP product (also known as TPW)

COM files will still be out of your reach, but at least DOS exe files should run in dosbox. Keep in mind that COM files have a 64k limitation, and therefore are of limited interest.

Free Pascal is working on a [DOS16-bit Dos compiler](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/[1]) that can generate com files directly from (64-bit) Windows, and while it is working, it is not released yet.

Comment: How would I make TP7 target DOS?

Comment: As said there are multiple editions. _IF_ you have a version that supports it, it is probably configurable in the compiler or options menu. I no longer know its menus by heart. I migrated to Free Pascal long ago